# Java - Information from error message

Tags: java, compiler-errors

What does this error message tell about signature of missing constructor ?

Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.thrift.transport.TSocket.(Ljava/lang/String;III)V

Does it mean that there is no constructor with single String argument ? I am more interesting in knowing what "III" and "V" are here for.

Thanks.

Comment: Can we see the code of yours that raises this exception?

Comment: may this help you http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/types.html#wp276

Answer (score 6):

When you see `Ljava/lang/String;`, yes, that is a `String` in the signature, here it is first.

The three `I`s mean three additional `int` arguments.

After the ending parentheses, the `V` means a return type of `void`.

The signature is `(String, int, int, int)` returning `void`.

[This page](http://journals.ecs.soton.ac.uk/java/tutorial/native1.1/implementing/method.html) contains a listing of what each symbol means.

Answer (score 2):

It's looking for the constructor `(String, int, int, int)`
V means that is `void`. Constructors return `void` which is the reason for the V at the end of the signature.

> (Ljava/lang/String;III)V
>
> Ljava/lang/String; (L fully-qualified-class ;)
>
> III (int,int,int)
>
> V -> return type void

This link may help you [types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/types.html#wp276)

```
For example, the Java method:

long f (int n, String s, int[] arr); 
has the following type signature:

(ILjava/lang/String;[I)J
```